# EF 5 Linq related entities is always null

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have an entity AllocatedContainers which has a foreign key to InventoryContainerDetails.

When I execute the below linq query it returns records where there are no related table entries in AllocatedContainers, but when there is supposed to be a joined record in AllocatedContainer, that entire row is not being returned. Can't figure out Why?

Here is the class, note the virtual relation to AllocatedContainer

```
public partial class InventoryContainerDetail
{
    public InventoryContainerDetail()
    {
        this.AllocatedContainers = new HashSet<AllocatedContainer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InventoryContainerHeaderId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceiptDetailId { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyInContainer { get; set; }


    public virtual InventoryContainerHeader InventoryContainerHeader { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AllocatedContainer> AllocatedContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the query:

```
IQueryable<InventoryContainerDetail> containerDtlsToAllocateOLD = 
                repository
                    .SearchFor(
                        x => x.InventoryContainerHeader.FacilityId == intFacilityId
                        && x.ItemId == intItemId
                        && (x.QtyInContainer - x.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty)) > 0
                    )
                    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn);
```

Which puts out this SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[Id1] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Project2].[InventoryContainerHeaderId] AS [InventoryContainerHeaderId], 
[Project2].[ItemId] AS [ItemId], 
[Project2].[ReceiptDetailId] AS [ReceiptDetailId], 
[Project2].[QtyInContainer] AS [QtyInContainer], 
[Project2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
[Project2].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Project2].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
[Project2].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
[Project2].[AllocationNeedId] AS [AllocationNeedId], 
[Project2].[AllocatedContainerDetailId] AS [AllocatedContainerDetailId], 
[Project2].[AllocatedQty] AS [AllocatedQty], 
[Project2].[CreatedById1] AS [CreatedById1], 
[Project2].[CreatedOn1] AS [CreatedOn1], 
[Project2].[ModifiedById1] AS [ModifiedById1], 
[Project2].[ModifiedOn1] AS [ModifiedOn1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[InventoryContainerHeaderId] AS [InventoryContainerHeaderId], 
    [Project1].[ItemId] AS [ItemId], 
    [Project1].[ReceiptDetailId] AS [ReceiptDetailId], 
    [Project1].[QtyInContainer] AS [QtyInContainer], 
    [Project1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
    [Project1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Project1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
    [Project1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id2], 
    [Extent4].[AllocationNeedId] AS [AllocationNeedId], 
    [Extent4].[AllocatedContainerDetailId] AS [AllocatedContainerDetailId], 
    [Extent4].[AllocatedQty] AS [AllocatedQty], 
    [Extent4].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById1], 
    [Extent4].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn1], 
    [Extent4].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById1], 
    [Extent4].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[InventoryContainerHeaderId] AS [InventoryContainerHeaderId], 
        [Extent1].[ItemId] AS [ItemId], 
        [Extent1].[ReceiptDetailId] AS [ReceiptDetailId], 
        [Extent1].[QtyInContainer] AS [QtyInContainer], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[FacilityId] AS [FacilityId], 
        (SELECT 
            SUM([Extent3].[AllocatedQty]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[AllocatedContainers] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[AllocatedContainerDetailId]) AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[InventoryContainerDetail] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[InventoryContainerHeader] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[InventoryContainerHeaderId] = [Extent2].[Id] ) AS [Project1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AllocatedContainers] AS [Extent4] ON [Project1].[Id] = [Extent4].[AllocatedContainerDetailId]
    WHERE (([Project1].[QtyInContainer] - [Project1].[C1]) > cast(0 as decimal(18))) AND ([Project1].[FacilityId] = 1) AND ([Project1].[ItemId] = 3027)
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[CreatedOn] ASC, [Project2].[Id1] ASC, [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

Here is the repository method. Note I am inducing eager loading via the .Include in hopes of it working, but no luck:

```
public override IQueryable<InventoryContainerDetail> SearchFor(Expression<Func<InventoryContainerDetail, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<InventoryContainerDetail, bool>> orderbylinq = null)
        {
            if (orderbylinq == null)
            {
                return DbSet.Include("AllocatedContainers").Where(predicate);
            }
            else
            {
                return DbSet.Include("AllocatedContainers").Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderbylinq);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the code of `DbSet`?

Comment: Can you please use `ToString` instead of `ToList` in the query to get generated SQL and add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks @LasislavMrnka for taking a look. I've added the generated SQL.

Comment: Ok, actually it is working...I changed "&& (x.QtyInContainer - x.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty)) > 0" to this "&& (x.QtyInContainer - (x.AllocatedContainers.Count() == 0 ? 0 : x.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty))) > 0". Thanks Ladislav for showing me that trick...you can then take that actual sql and paste it in SQL Server and help debug from there too, which is great.

Comment: When stepping through code in debugmode, you can mouse over whatever variable is going to be the result of the query and have the debugger show you the SQL (uses the same .ToString() method) before the part that calls .ToList() You can then copy that from the debug window to SQL MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually it is working...I changed
 `"&& (x.QtyInContainer - x.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty)) > 0"` 
to this
 `"&& (x.QtyInContainer - (x.AllocatedContainers.Count() == 0 ? 0 : x.AllocatedContainers.Sum(a => a.AllocatedQty))) > 0"`.

Thanks Ladislav for showing me that trick...you can then take that actual sql and paste it in SQL Server and help debug from there too, which is great